# How to create a jquery single mouseenter() events for different classes

Tags: jquery, mouseenter

Hi I am trying to group a series of mouseenter events to one but I am really new to javascript and getting really confused I want to create one event to include them all.".slider-button-1" classes counting to 5 for now.

```
$("#slider-s-pic .slider-button-1").mouseenter(function () {
    $(".slider-inner ul").animate({ marginLeft: "-" + (liWidth * 0) + "px" });
});
```

My whole project is in codepen -> [codepen.io/FreeMaNn/pen/ZagweX](http://codepen.io/FreeMaNn/pen/ZagweX)

Comment: Is the number with the class `.slider-button-` is using anywhere? If not, assign same class name to all the buttons, like `.slider-button`.

Comment: @Madhavan.V Yes it's used in a couple of image tags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use something like

```
$("#slider-s-pic a[class^='slider-button-']").mouseenter(function () {
    var GetIndex = $(this).closest('li').index();
    $(".slider-inner ul").animate({ 
       marginLeft: "-" + (liWidth * GetIndex) + "px" 
     });
});
```

`a[class^='slider-button-']` - select all classes which starts with `slider-button-`

`^` - starts with
`*` - contains
`$` - ends with

`var GetIndex = $(this).closest('li').index();` - get the `li` index .. Don't use `$(this).index()` it'll return 0 each time .. so you need to use `.closest('li')`

Comment: Thanks a lot friend.I've been searching this for a week :)

Comment: @Jr.FreeMaNn you're totally welcome .. Have a great day :)

Answer (score 0):

Your selectors will be comma (,) separated. Try it

```
$("#slider-s-pic , .slider-button-1").mouseenter(function () {
    $(".slider-inner ul").animate({ marginLeft: "-" + (liWidth * 0) + "px" });
});
```

Comment: Your solution is true but not flexible.For example; when i add new slider image, i have to add new class in this mouseenter event.
I want the code I wrote to be more flexible

Answer (score 0):

Try it. It will work.

```
$(document).on( 'mouseenter', '#slider-s-pic , .slider-button-1',(function () {
    $(".slider-inner ul").animate({ marginLeft: "-" + (liWidth * 0) + "px" });
});
```